# How do I responsively shrink white space between elements in a row

Tags: html, css

Given the design below where the green bits are white space that can resize and the mountains are fixed size images that can not change size. How can I code this so that it will responsively resize (no javascript).

[image]

The initial widths of both the white space and the images are all different.

The green spaces need to scale down proportionally so that when one green space is 50% of its origional width all green spaces are 50% of their origional width.

Not use a flexbox. Needs further back compatability.

This is what it would look like after half the green space has gone.

[image]

Comment: Consider using `%`-based margins on the images, but flex is really the best option for this.

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: I can think of a few ways but without seeing your markup. I don't know which would be best for your situation.

Comment: @MoshFeu I don't have nay markup yet. I'm not sure what the best approach is.

Comment: Is @Rounin's answer good for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider giving each image its own `%`-based `margin-right` after declaring its `width`:

```css
div {
white-space:nowrap;
}

img {
height: 120px;
}

img:nth-of-type(1) {
width: 126px;
margin-left:3%;
margin-right:2%;
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
width: 168px;
margin-right:1%;
}

img:nth-of-type(3) {
width: 84px;
margin-right:6%;
}

img:nth-of-type(4) {
width: 28px;
margin-right:3%;
}

img:nth-of-type(5) {
width: 42px;
margin-right:2%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/29426/pexels-photo-29426.jpg" alt="Mountains" />
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/29426/pexels-photo-29426.jpg" alt="Mountains" />
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/29426/pexels-photo-29426.jpg" alt="Mountains" />
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/29426/pexels-photo-29426.jpg" alt="Mountains" />
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/29426/pexels-photo-29426.jpg" alt="Mountains" />
</div>
```

---

**N.B.** I was initially going to suggest using CSS viewport width units (`vw`) rather than `%`.

But I see MDN states:

> Only Gecko-based browsers are updating the viewport values
>   dynamically, when the size of the viewport is modified (by modifying
>   the size of the window on a desktop computer or by turning the device
>   on a phone or a tablet).

**See:** http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths

Comment: Almost works. However items break onto the next line before the gaps have fully closed.

Comment: Yep. Easily fixed. You can prevent wrapping by enclosing the elements in a div and declaring the style `white-space: nowrap` for that div. See my amendment to the solution above.